# gRPC Streaming In React Not Working As Expected

Tags: reactjs, streaming, grpc, grpc-web

I'm trying to test out gRPC streaming in my react app. Although I'm having some troubles.
We've tested our streaming in bloom and it successfully streams an event every 2 seconds up to 8 streams.

However when I try it out in my React Application the stream starts, then nothing happens for quite some time (around about equal to the time it takes to finish streaming all the data), then it only logs out all the data at once.

This is how I have my component set up:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const startStream = () => {
    console.log('stream start')
    const streamer = myService.testStreaming(new Empty(), {})
    streamer.on('error', err => console.log({ err }))
    streamer.on('status', status => console.log({ status }))
    streamer.on('data', response => console.log(response.toObject()))
    streamer.on('end', () => console.log('stream end'))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    startStream()
  }, [])

  return null
}
```

As mentioned above, my output is `stream start` *wait +- 15 seconds* then `8 lines of responses`.

As mentioned, in bloom it successfully sends through a new stream every 2 seconds as expected. Unlike in my React app where it just waits a long time and then triggers the `on data` callback 8 times immediately.

[image: Bloom]

[image: Console]

In my Network Tab, the StreamEvents is jsut in a pending start for +- 15 seconds as well.

Comment: It wasn't mentioned in the issue description - which grpc-web proxy are you using?

Comment: Just the default one as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you're using the text mode of grpc-web, as the binary format doesn't currently support proper streaming:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/344#issuecomment-433288348

Comment: Yeah that's not the issue, we're already using `mode=grpcwebtext`

Comment: Ah right, the JS Output in our protos still had binary mode set. My bad...  Thanks this sorted it!

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle could you help me understand how and where you changed it so the protos didn't have binary mode set? Thanks -

Comment: I did it in the protoc -I=.... for my generation script.

Comment: I'm using this protocol command:

protoc -I=. src/ping_pong.proto --js_out=import_style=commonjs:. --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle I think that with import_style=commonjs that should not generate them in binary mode as I have also set the proper `mode`

Comment: Yeah but I had previously explicitly set to mode=binary for some reason (I run it in a script)